# Does OCaml support call-by-name parameter passing?

Tags: ocaml, lazy-evaluation

Scala allows function parameters to be *call-by-name* using the '`=>`' syntax. For example, the boolean `and` function can be defined as:

```scala
def and(x: Boolean, y: => Boolean): Boolean =
  if (x) y else false
```

The second parameter is call-by-name. This ensures the expected "short-circuiting" behaviour – if `x` is `false`, `y` will not be evaluated at all.

In general, this is useful for functions where a parameter might not be used at all.

How can this be done in OCaml?

I am aware that OCaml has constructs for lazy evaluation, but it is not clear to me if and how these could be used for call-by-name parameter passing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, by construction, boolean operators are lazy:

```ml
# false || (print_endline "second"; true);;
second
- : bool = true
# true || (print_endline "second"; true);;
- : bool = true
# true && (print_endline "second"; false);;
second
- : bool = false
# false && (print_endline "second"; false);;
- : bool = false
```

Then, for more custom functions, you should indeed use lazy (with the huge benefit that lazy values are memoised after being evaluated):

```ml
let fib n =
  let rec aux n b a =
    Printf.printf "%d %d %d\n" n b a;
    if n <= 0 then a else aux (n - 1) (a + b) b
  in
  aux n 1 0

let f a b = if b > 0 then Lazy.force a + 1 else b
(* val f : int lazy_t -> int -> int = <fun> *)

let () =
  let r = lazy (fib 10) in
  let r2 = lazy (fib 1000000) in
  Printf.printf "%d\n" (f r 1 + f r 2 + f r2 0)
```

The result will be:

```
10 1 0
9 1 1
8 2 1
7 3 2
6 5 3
5 8 5
4 13 8
3 21 13
2 34 21
1 55 34
0 89 55
112
```

`r` has only be evaluated once and `r2` has never been evaluated.

Comment: I take it from your answer that if we attempted to define the `and` operator in such a way, it would have type `bool -> bool lazy_t -> bool`, necessitating invocations to wrap the second argument in a `lazy`. If this is so, how are the boolean operators in OCaml actually defined? Are they just intrinsic, and unable to be defined in the language itself?

Comment: Boolean operators are defined as compiler primitives (see https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/lambda/translprim.ml#L139) but I never really dug that deep in the compiler to know how they're written and what they do. If someone like @gasche would like to explain it here briefly, that would be nice

Comment: I am not sure what there is to explain? Both `||` and `&&` are defined as compiler primitives in the standard library with `external (||): bool -> bool -> bool = "%seqor"` and `external (&&): bool -> bool -> bool = "%seqand"` (compiler primitive names start with `%`). And the compiler is implementing the usual short-circuiting semantics for `%seqor` and `%seqand`.

Comment: You actually pointed what there is to explain, `And the compiler is implementing the usual short-circuiting semantics for %seqor and %seqand`. Since op asked `Are they just intrinsic, and unable to be defined in the language itself?` I answered that they are intrinsics but I don't think they can be defined in the language itself but I wouldn't be able to explain it. So that's all, "would you be able to define an operator like `&&` without using lazy?". My instinct is that you can't but I can't explain what the compiler does for them.

Comment: I really don't understand your comment @octachron. I wrote that boolean operators are defined as compiler primitives but that I don't know how they're compiled and hence can not explain what is done behind and you commented "boolean operators are compiler primitives and the compiler is compiling them, I don't know what there is to explain". My question was specifically about "how are they compiled and is it doable in an OCaml program?"

Comment: Maybe a better phrasing would be that no OCaml is always call-by-value, and `||` can no more be implemented as function than `if ... then ... else..`.  In other words, `x || y` and `x && y` are semantics shortcut for `if x then true else y` and `if x then y else false` with the usual semantics for `if ... then ... else`. In particular, `((||) true) (Printf.printf "not short-circuiting\n"; true)` does print on stdout because `(||) true` buy a closure which is no longer a compiler primitive.

Comment: But sequand and sequor are defined in OCaml files, that's why I don't fully understand why you couldn't rewrite them yourself. If they were primitives in C files, I'd understand it. But they're not.

Comment: The semantics of those primitives are defined by the compiler. To rewrite `||` in OCaml, you would need to encode the primitive `%seqand` into another primitive for instance `if ... then ... else ...`.  Note that the OCaml compiler is written fully in OCaml, it is only the runtime which is written in C. Nevertheless, the semantics of the compiler implementation language is irrelevant for the semantics of the compiled programs. For instance, you could totally write a Haskell compiler in OCaml.

Comment: I suppose a simpler way I could have asked my follow-up question is whether it is possible to define a function with a call-by-name parameter in a way that provides the same _interface_ for the caller as a call-by-value function. This is the case in Scala, and in the OCaml boolean operators. But for user-defined functions in OCaml, I take it from this conversation that the answer is no.